# Конвертировать PFX в PEM

Tags: openssl, pem

Есть PFX-сертификат, защищенный паролем.

При выполнении

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -out cert.pem -passin pass:****** -nodes
```

Генерируется PEM-сертификат, но в нем лежит приватный ключ

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Если смотреть на прошлый, просроченный сертификат, то в нем указан приватный ключ

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Как получить такой PEM-сертификат?

update:

Сгенерировать отдельно ключ можно так

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -nocerts -nodes | openssl rsa -out privkey.pem
```

Answer (score 1):

Я понимаю, что вопрос может быть для вас уже давно неактуален, но ради будущих поколений, которые получат ссылку в гугле и будут искать ответ, спрошу - вы уверены, что в вашем файле `cert.pfx` действительно есть сертификат? Команда `openssl pkcs12` выводит всё содержимое контейнера, и если бы там были сертификаты, то они были бы экспортированы.

Для примера я перегнал сертификат, выданный Let's Encrypt, в формат pkcs12 
`openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey privkey.pem -in fullchain.pem -out my-site.pfx -password pass:***`
и вот что получил.

Команда `openssl pkcs12 -in my-site.pfx -info -nodes -passin pass:***` выводит содержимое контейнера в формате PEM:

```
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 42 98 C1 69 0F 61 99 B8 76 51 82 CE 4C 9D E0 2F A6 F4 49 54
subject=CN = <my-site>

issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes: <No Attributes>
subject=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3

issuer=O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 42 98 C1 69 0F 61 99 B8 76 51 82 CE 4C 9D E0 2F A6 F4 49 54
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Экспорт только сертификата сайта: `openssl pkcs12 -in my-site.pfx -nokeys -clcerts -passin pass:*** > my-site.pem`

Экспорт сертификата удостоверяющего центра: `openssl pkcs12 -in my-site.pfx -nokeys -cacerts -passin pass:*** > ca-cert.pem`

Я думаю, что в вашем файле есть только приватный ключ, а собственно сертификат отсутствует.